# Python Selenium Data does not load (website Security)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, geckodriver

Please find the code below with which I was trying to download/scrape a "csv" file.   The code is the first stage while testing and it fails, even though there is no error.  --Data does not load in the gecko driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Py378\prj14\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market")
time.sleep(5)

element_dorpdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("equitieStockSelect"))
element_dorpdown.select_by_index(44)   #Updated with help of @PDHide in the comments
time.sleep(5)
```

The code executes ok, but the data related to the option does not load due to the security settings of the website, and when I manually select and update the option, table doesnt update, as if there was no selection made. (Maybe its getting to know its selenium driver, and needs headers, but not sure...) Also, when I try to click on "Download in CSV", it gives timeout.

[image]

I need to download the csv for F&O, after the option is selected successfully(as shown above)... Please Help...

I can browse through the website on normal browser(installed), but when I use python(selenium) it just fails on those browsers... how to by-pass the security please???

Comment: add the html dom

Comment: @PDHide , thanks for responding PDHide... but not sure how to do that, I am just learning this one.. would you be so kind to help with that one pls..

Comment: copy what you get when pressing f12 , select calss works only with select tag

Comment: @PDHide , ok by what I understand from your suggestion, I have updated the code this way;.... element_dorpdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("no-border-radius")) ... but still it doesnt update the option... (maybe its detecting selenium driver, and needs headers, but not sure.. just guessing)

Comment: @PDHide , the page just times-out when I try to update the option or even when downloading the csv from the page manually(not with python).. are you sure you are trying through selenium, because my page just fails to update after first step of getting the webpage

Comment: you can use Selec(findelement) only if the lement you are tying to find is <select id bala bla >

Comment: @PDHide , yes I understand, and here is what I am trying to select... :::   <select id="equitieStockSelect" class="no-border-radius">    .. in the code above I have the "id" and after your suggestion, I have tried class... can you please try it and let me know if you are able to get through with the download....

Comment: See select by index works , else see if the element is in iframe or something

Comment: thanks @PDHide , now the element is getting selected, but the page doesn't give the data as if it knows I am opening through selenium... or scraping.. maybe it is detecting the browser... when I do it through chrome(normal) or firefox(normal), it doesn't give any problems... but when I run the script though selenium, it doesn't show the data or allow download of data... can you please help... I have tried Headers... but doesn;t seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225317/discussion-between-lokkii9-and-pdhide).

Comment: just add proper waits

Comment: @PDHide somehow this seems like a deadend as even with a wait(time.sleep(1500), it only gives me "Session Timed Out" error....  If you have really tired and able to download, please post an answer... and I will mark it as solution...

Comment: yes i tried it seems you have to hack chromedriver

Comment: just search how to stop website from detecting selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried executing the code (using Chrome, but that shouldn't matter) or should I say, a slight variation of it so I could better see what was going on (note that I use `implicitly_wait` rather than `sleep`, the latter being wasteful of time). Here I am just trying to select the second option:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(3) # wait up to 3 seconds before calls to find elements time out
    driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market")
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("equitieStockSelect"))
    select.select_by_index(1)
finally:
    input('pausing...')
    driver.quit()
```

As you can see, I have no problem selecting the second option. However, the new table is failing to load:

At this point I manually issue a reload on the page and I get the results below. My conclusion is that the website is detecting that the browser is being run by automation and is preventing the access:

**Update**

So the data can be retrieved using `requests`. I used the Chrome inspector to look at network XHR requests and then I selected the second option (NIFTY NEXT 50) and observed what AJAX request was being made:

[image]

In this case the URL was: `https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%20NEXT%2050`. However, you have to first fetch the initial page using a `requests` `Session` instance:

```
import requests

try:
    s = requests.Session()
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
    s.headers.update(headers)
    # You have to first retrieve the initial page:
    resp = s.get('https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    #print(resp.text)
    resp = s.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%20NEXT%2050')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    data = resp.json()
    print(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Prints:

```
{'name': 'NIFTY NEXT 50', 'advance': {'declines': '25', 'advances': '24', 'unchanged': '1'}, 'timestamp': '27-Nov-2020 16:00:00', 'data': [{'priority': 1, 'symbol': 'NIFTY NEXT 50', 'identifier': 'NIFTY NEXT 50', 'open': 30316.45,  etc. (data too long) }
```

**Update 2**

In general, to compute the URL you need to get any index, for example index 44, look at the corresponding option value for that index, in this case 'Securities in F&O' and substitute that for variable `option_value` in the following program:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

option_value = 'SECURITIES IN F&O'

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=' + quote_plus(option_value)
print(url)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES+IN+F%26O
```

The above URL is the value to use.

Comment: Thanks @Booboo, yes please, I had updated the page/question a few minutes back... I was able to get the option to change, but there is no help online on how to by pass the security of the webpage...  I am unable to find any blog/selenium modules on this aspect...

Comment: I am not aware of how to use requests library which is standard python lib...  I am unsure if that will have a way to bypass security for the same..

Comment: I've updated the answer using `requests`. Sorry, I accidentally deleted a couple of the images from the earlier answer.

Comment: thank you soo much for this @Booboo... reallly appreciate your solution... and I have one more request...  The initial post was for "Securities in F&O" or "index_value(44)".. As I am new to the library, would you plsss be kind to suggest for that one please... in the line of ["resp = s.get......]

Comment: The URL would be: `https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES%20IN%20F%26O`. See updated answer.